# Cannot read property of undefined on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting up a client code and the error "Cannot read property '' of undefined" keeps occur.

> TypeError: Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

It is interesting that if I refresh the page several times then suddenly it works! For example, the home page is random within 10 times, menu page shows me an error page at the first time, half loaded at first refresh, fully loaded at second refresh.

I think props can't get data correctly right away. So I think I can solve this problem by refreshing automatically until props get correct data.

Is there any way refreshing until I get the props?

Or any other solution about this problem?

**menu error**

[image]

**home error**

[image]

Comment: you can check with the prop is defined before use it; or you can check react suspense, maybe it could be useful

Comment: Are these objects being populated with asynchronous data? Either check that it is defined before trying to access it, or prepopulate the objects with empty data.

Comment: you have a race condition. It appears likely (can't tell without code) you are using a graphQL query to retrieve both the `user` object and the `data` object. And, in both cases you are attempting to use them prior to them being available. You get lucky upon refresh sometimes and the query returns in time. Apply some async coding practices - wait for the results prior to attempting to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need check exist of `data`, and then fields in this object:

```
loading || (data && (!data.me || !data.getPlaces)) ? ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your if condition to:

```
{loading || !data || !data.me ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you will need to confirm that the data object exists before doing a conditional. so

`loading || {data || !data.me || !data.getPlaces}`